# Split up keyword query individual parts loop

Tags: php, sqlite

I have Chinese php search queries.

I want to split up any query up into individual characters.

ex: 你好 (ni hao, hello) split into 你 and 好

my query is set like:

```
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
```

the results I want to split is set up like:

```
$results4 = $db->query( "SELECT CHS, PIN, DEF FROM FOUR 
                         WHERE CHS LIKE '%".$q."%' OR PIN LIKE '%".$q."%'");
while ($row4 = $results4->fetchArray()) {
```

How can I split up the keyword and look up all the components?

Comment: Do you want to check "chs like ni, or pin like ni", "chs like hao or pin like nao" and so on? Or something completely different?

Comment: The top rated comment on http://php.net/str_split gives a function to split unicode strings http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php#107658

Comment: @RST basically 你好 -> chs like 你 & chs like 好

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it all in one query you will have to generate the whole query. If you were looking for an exact match you could use something similar to the `in_array()` function, but with `LIKE` it doesn't work.

You could however loop through the array of characters and put together the `WHERE` part programatically.

Like this

```
$where = array();
foreach ( $qtwo as $word ) {
   $where[] = "CHS LIKE '%" . $word . "%'";
}

$where = implode(' OR ', $where);
```

Use this `$where` variable in your query

Comment: getting an error with this **foreach**： Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: you may have to change `$qtwo` to something else if your array that holds the single characters is named differently. I used `$qtwo` because you mentioned that in a comment to the other answer.

Comment: Unable to prepare statement: 1, near "%"

Comment: var_dump($where); returns this: "CHS LIKE %你% OR CHS LIKE %好%" what is the problem?!

Comment: `$results4 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM FOUR WHERE $where");`

Comment: adjusted the quotes for the `WHERE` part

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to convert a string in an array of chars

```
$chars = str_split($q)
```

Comment: $qtwo[0] works, is there a function like $qtwo[n] to include all variables in an array?

Comment: I'm running this atm: `"SELECT CHS, PIN, DEF FROM FOUR WHERE CHS LIKE '%".$qtwo[0]."%' OR CHS LIKE '%".$qtwo[1]."%'"` but there must be something I can do like $qtwo[$x] or whatever

Comment: I don't undertand what you're looking for. Using str_split the string 你好 will become Array([0] => 你, [1] => 好)

Comment: using the snippet posted by @RST `$query = "SELECT CHS, PIN, DEF FROM FOUR WHERE ";foreach($chars as $char){$where[] = 'CHS LIKE %'.$char.'%';} $query .= implode(' OR ', $where);`